# Strength order of code executing (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

I got strength problem when part of code which is closer to procedure end executes first comparing with part of code which close to procedure start

```
var count = 0
        var save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

         Alamofire.request(.GET, "")
                .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { (request, response, string, error) -> Void in

                    println("res: "+string!)
                    count = string!.toInt()!


            }

println(count)
```

Here. First Alamofire makes request and set response data to variable "count". Second I'm printing count value to check it out.

In debugger I see

[image]

How can it be so that first I see "count" value printed and then I see Alamofire response? How should I fix it? I need count to be a alamofire-response converted from string into integer

Comment: Just an FYI, sometimes it might be worth posting your actual code rather than an image so people can copy and paste it to their computers. This might make it easier to help you :)

Comment: The AlamoFire README explicitly mentions the asynchronous nature of request: *"Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously. ... The result of a request is only available inside the scope of a response handler."*. – The linked-to thread is #1 on the "frequent" tab of [tag:alamofire].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requests made using this API are asynchronous. That means your code continues execution and calls `println(count)` **before** the code in the response closure is executed. URL requests take time, and asynchronous code is required to prevent blocking the main thread.

You will need to restructure your code to account for the fact that you are working with asynchronous method calls. For example, your method above may need to take a `completion` closure of its own that you call from within the response's closure, and pass your `count` back there.

```
func executeRequest(completion: (count: Int) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://my1test.ru/applejesus.php?task=getCategoryCount").responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { (request, response, string, error) -> Void in
        println("res: "+string!)
        let count = string!.toInt()!
        completion(count)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Alamofire` works `asynchronously` which means it will perform the task in the background and move on to the rest of the code. So in this case the code is executing at the same time. Performing tasks `asynchronously` helps to increase performance especially in larger programs where just executing code one after another would take a long time.

A simple fix would be to put the print statement inside the `Alamofire` block